# Java Highlighter Continues to Highlight

Tags: java, documentlistener

I have the following code for Highlighting and can't figure out why It continues to highlight beyond the ranges specified.

```
        class DocListener implements DocumentListener {

        Color Valid_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
        Color Error_COLOR = Color.PINK;
        HostCollectionTextField field;
        Pattern p;
        Matcher m;
        private String valid = "(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.(\\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.]))|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s+(25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s*\\/(\\d{1,3}))?";

        public DocListener(Component field) {
            this.field = (HostCollectionTextField) field;
            p = Pattern.compile(valid);

        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
         //   System.out.println("insert:" + field.getText());
            m = p.matcher(this.field.getText());
            while (m.find()) {
                try {
                    String b = m.group();
                    System.out.println(b);
                    int index = field.getText().indexOf(b);
                    System.out.println("index=" + index);
                    int end = index + b.length();
                    System.out.println("end=" + end);
                    Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Valid_COLOR);

                    this.field.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, end, painter);

                    System.out.println(">> " + b.substring(2, b.length() - 2));
                } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            System.out.println("removing text");
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

            System.out.println("Change:" + field.getText());
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

You can see the problem in the picture below.

Only valid matches should be highlighted, yet the highlighter never stops highlighting.

Here is my SSCCE

```
public class SSCCE extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form SSCCE
 */
public SSCCE() {
    initComponents();
    this.textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocListener(this.textField));
}

class DocListener implements DocumentListener {

    Color Valid_COLOR = Color.GREEN;
    Color Error_COLOR = Color.PINK;
    JTextField field;
    Pattern p;
    Matcher m;
    Highlighter.HighlightPainter painter;
    private String valid = "(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2}\\.(\\d{1,3}))(?:(?:-|\\s+to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?![\\d\\.]))|(?:-|\\s*to\\s+)(\\d{1,3}(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s+(25\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})|\\s*\\/(\\d{1,3}))?";

    public DocListener(Component field) {
        this.field = (JTextField) field;
        p = Pattern.compile(valid);

    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("insert:" + field.getText());
        m = p.matcher(this.field.getText());
        ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList();
        while (m.find()) {
            try {
                String b = m.group();
                matches.add(b);
                int index = m.start();
                int end = m.end();
                System.out.println("start:" + index + " end:" + end);                   
                painter = new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Valid_COLOR);
                this.field.getHighlighter().addHighlight(index, end, painter);

            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        System.out.println("removing text");
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {

        System.out.println("Change:" + field.getText());
    }
}


/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    textField = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    textField.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addComponent(textField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 408, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(110, 110, 110)
            .addComponent(textField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(170, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SSCCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SSCCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SSCCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SSCCE.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SSCCE().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JTextField textField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I've just used the values from the Matcher to set the start/end values of the Highlighter:

```
int start = matcher.start(i);
int end = matcher.end(i);
inputArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight( start, end, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter );
```

Here is the complete code to demonstrate this functionality:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class RegexKing implements ActionListener, DocumentListener
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new RegexKing();
    }

    public RegexKing()
    {
        initGUI();
        setupGUI();
        displayFrame();

    }

    public void initGUI()
    {
        // init
        frame = new JFrame("Regex King");
        container = new JPanel();

        inputArea = new JTextArea();
        regexField =new JTextField();
        outputArea = new JTextArea();

        quickMatch = new JCheckBox("Attempt Match on Change");
        matchButton = new JButton("Match");

        inputScroll = new JScrollPane(inputArea);
        outputScroll = new JScrollPane(outputArea);

        // setup
        outputArea.setEditable(false);
        matchButton.addActionListener(this);
        regexField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

        // key binding
        KeyStroke key = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, Event.SHIFT_MASK, false);
        Action keyact = new AbstractAction()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                doMatch();
            }
        };

        container.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(key, "DO_MATCH");
        container.getActionMap().put("DO_MATCH", keyact);

    }

    public void setupGUI()
    {
        gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        container.setLayout(gbl);

        setInsets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        gbcf = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        setComp(inputScroll, 10, 10, 20, 1, 1, 1);
        setComp(quickMatch, 10, 20, 1, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(matchButton, 20, 20, 1, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(regexField, 10, 30, 20, 1, 1, .1);
        setComp(outputScroll, 10, 40, 20, 1, 1, 1);
    }

    public void setComp(JComponent comp, int gx, int gy, int gw, int gh, double wx, double wy)
    {
        gbc.gridx = gx;
        gbc.gridy = gy;
        gbc.gridwidth = gw;
        gbc.gridheight = gh;
        gbc.weightx = wx;
        gbc.weighty = wy;

        gbc.fill = gbcf;

        gbl.setConstraints(comp, gbc);
        container.add(comp);
    }

    public void setInsets(int top, int bottom, int left, int right)
    {
        gbc.insets.top = top;
        gbc.insets.bottom = bottom;
        gbc.insets.left = left;
        gbc.insets.right = right;
    }

    public void displayFrame()
    {
        frame.setContentPane(container);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(quickMatch.isSelected() == true)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e)
    {
        if(quickMatch.isSelected() == true)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e)  {}


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        if(evt.getSource() == matchButton)
        {
            doMatch();
        }
    }

    public void doMatch()
    {
        outputArea.setText("\nAttempting Match...");
        inputArea.getHighlighter().removeAllHighlights();

        try
        {

            String inputText = inputArea.getText();
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexField.getText());
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputText);

            int matchCount = 0;

            while(matcher.find())
            {

                matchCount++;
                outputArea.append("\n\nMatch #" + matchCount);

                for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount() + 1; i++)
                {
                    outputArea.append("\nGroup #" + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
                    outputArea.append(" , " + matcher.end(i));
                    int start = matcher.start(i);
                    int end = matcher.end(i);
                    inputArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight( start, end, DefaultHighlighter.DefaultPainter );

                    if (matchCount == 1) inputArea.setCaretPosition(start);
                }

            }

        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            outputArea.append("\nEXCEPTION THROWN");
        }

        outputArea.append("\n\nFinished.\n");

    }

    GridBagLayout gbl;
    GridBagConstraints gbc;
    int gbcf;

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel container;

    JTextArea inputArea;
    JTextField regexField;
    JTextArea outputArea;

    JScrollPane inputScroll;
    JScrollPane outputScroll;

    JCheckBox quickMatch;
    JButton matchButton;

}
```

Enter some text in the top text area. Enter the search string in the text field. If the check box is selected matching will be done as you change the search string. If the check box is not select you need to click the "Match" button. Some debug info will appear in the second text area.

Don't forget to implement the removeUpdate(...) method since removing a character from the document can change the highlighting.

Comment: Not quite what i'm going for. In my code above I have to document listener to verify input as its being typed. When a valid input is detected, it needs to be highlighted within the string that the user typed. There can be multiple matches in the input string, thus the start and end indices must be  the indices within the entered string. The problem is, invalid indices are being highlighted even though the valid indicies are 0, 8.

Comment: @JamieSnipes, post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Just posted the SSCCE above.